# get full url link with language prefix in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, http-host, request-uri

I want to get the language prefix from url with Wordpress, but I don't know how.
if I have the following url `http://sitename.com/ru/about-us`, I want to get the full path including `/ru/`, but whatever I try i don't get it ,e.g

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

I am using qTranslate plugin, and my site it multilanguage

I just want to check if the url link has language prefix after host name, I can do that if i get the whole url, but I can't get it, anybody can help me?

Comment: Is this single or multisite installation?

Comment: it is mulitlanguage site, using qtranslate

Comment: run `echo var_dump($_SERVER);` and look at result. maybe helps.

Comment: REDIRECT_URL, that is what i need, thanks @marioosh

Comment: @anulik It would be good to include the fact that it's a single site installation and multilanguage using qTranslate in your question (even if it is already resolved)! :-)

Comment: ok, just added, thanks for note

Comment: I'm not sure $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] will work for you to fix the multilang issues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483912/php-serverredirect-url-vs-serverrequest-uri What you tried to get the requested URI is the correct way! Let me know the results if you try the plugin I posted in my answer...

Comment: @Minister, i don't need to make any changes to my .htaccess, my main point is, i have 3 sites with different domeins, site.am, site.ru, site.com,wich are working with single db, and in db sTranslate has set as default language english, if i open site.ru my site default language must be russian, so my site language at first for site.ru must be russian

Comment: so in my functions.php i am just getting  the /ru/ or /en/ from my url, and if that prefixs are not exists i am changing language, if not just letting to qTranslate do his work                                 $q_config['default_language'] = $current_domain_lang;
$url = substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'],0,4);

if($url!="/en/" && $url!="/am/" && $url!="/ru/"){
 $q_config['language'] = $current_domain_lang;
 $q_config['default_language'] = $current_domain_lang;
}

Comment: it is working for me, i just get what i need

Comment: the point is i have tried to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], but i don't get the language prefix, it returns just /about-us/, but the $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] is including the lang prefix, /ru/about-us/,     see above, i have wrote in my question, that i had tried the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: OK, I'm not going to change your mind... Just cheched my WP+MU and [REDIRECT_URL] => /ru/contact/, and also: [REQUEST_URI] => /ru/contact/ (If some day it doesn't work as you may need, keep that in mind. It could be better to check your server config some day...)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems similar to another one. The fix could be to install the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/

It should fix the URL problems that as it seems qTranslate has.

Reference: [Keep the string prepended in request uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256805/wordpress-htaccess-keep-the-string-appended-to-url)

If not working, you may want to try all other suggested code...

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that with Permalinks option from your WP dash board. Go to Settings > Permalinks. Select Custom Structure and add this line `/ru/%postname%/`.

Comment: it won't work, there is few languages in my site, not only ru, there is also am, fr

Comment: Okay, so for that you can use the plugin mentioned by Minister below.